# Creating new open property

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am trying to do a blog project and I am using ado.net and I have 3-tier architecture.
In one classlibrary I have classes such as `User` and `Comments`:

```
public class User
{
 public int userID{ get; set; }
 public string userName{ get; set; }
 public string userPassword { get; set; }
 public string userMail{ get; set; }
}

public class Comments
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public int userID{ get; set; }
public string commentHeader{ get; set; }
public string commentContent{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to have a `userName` property in the `Comments` class. And I decided to create an open property in the `Comments` class.

Because I will show in these in a UI and I want to see the `UserName` along with `UserID`; for a better understanding about whom send this comment.

How I can create the following?

```
public string userName
{
    get
    {
       return //(what I have to write here) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple ways to do that.

Assuming you have list of `User`s in your code, you can query against that list and retrieve the `UserName` in your property. Something like:

```
public string userName
{
    get
    {
       return userList.Single(r=>r.UserID == this.UserID).UserName; // Use single  
       //if you are sure there's going to be a single record against a user ID
       //Otherwise you may use First / FirstOrDefault
    }
}
```

**Or**

you may use composition and place User object inside the Comments class.

```
public class Comments
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public User user { get; set; } // User object in Comments class
public string commentHeader{ get; set; }
public string commentContent{ get; set; }
}
```

and then in your property you can simply do:

```
public string userName
{
    get
    {
       return user.UserName;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your 2 great answer... but my userlist is in other class library(cause of 3 tier architecture)...how i can use my userList ?

Comment: In that case you can't really adopt the first option. You may get the UserName using the first method in your form. I suggest you keep the object of User inside the comments not just the UserID, It will easier to access and maintain later.

Comment: there is no other way ? Am I have to change all my project?İf is possible please offer me other solution ...Cant't I just write open property ?

Comment: @y.baris, I am not sure if I am getting you, you can setup a Method in your UI/other class and then you can return the user from your list of users based on the UserID, but it will not be related to your Comments class and will not be a good design as well

Comment: thanks for your answers.sorry for bothering you ...I am trying to do but it is not working.I am sure doesn't working cause of me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string userName
    {
        get
        {
            return userList.FirstOrDefault(user => user.userID == userID).userName;
        }
    }
```

where userList is

```
List<User> userList;
```